# Кастомный редирект htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно с ссылок вида:

```
/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?PAGE=(.*)
```

Сделать редирект на тоже самое только без ?PAGE= и того что дальше идет

```
/(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/
```

Пробовал вот так

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/([0-9]+)/?PAGE(.*)$ $1/$2/$3/ [R=301]
```

Не работает. 
Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} PAGE=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z_0-9-]+)/(\d+)/$ /$1/$2/$3/? [R=301,L]
```